# no any response when use httpclient in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i want to get data from my server with AsyncTask and then extract some and send to another location and get more info from that

for first section I'm using from this code for run my AsyncTask method and Cancel AsyncTask after some time (for no response...)

```
new MySecendServer(link, param,mInstagramSession).execute();
final ProgressDialog pd2 = new ProgressDialog(testActivity.this);
pd2.show();
final Timer tm = new Timer();
tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 count++;
                            if (count == 30) {
                                pd2.cancel();
                                tm.cancel();
                                new MySecendServer(.....) .cancel(true); }

            }
        });

        }
    }, 1, 1000);
```

then after get data from my server i try to get more info with this code but i don't get any response or exception i test this code in doInBackground And onPostExecute and no any diffrent and no any response

```
        try {
        String requestUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requestUrl);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (httpEntity == null) {
            throw new Exception("Request returns empty result");
        }
        InputStream stream = httpEntity.getContent();
        String response = StringUtil.streamToString(stream);
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new Exception(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

now anyone can give me reason or any suggest for do this work ?
thanks

**Update :**

I found exception here :

```
HttpResponse httpResponse   = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

and message is :

> cause NetworkOnMainThreadException  (id=831620140512)

**Update 2 :**
My first AsyncTask

```
public class MySecendServerClass extends AsyncTask {

    private String link="";
    private String [][]pparams;
    private InstagramUser IG_User;
    private InstagramSession IG_Session;

    public MySecendServerClass(String link,String [][]params,InstagramSession user){
        this.link=link;
        this.pparams=params;
        this.IG_Session = user;

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        String data="";
        try{
        if(pparams!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<pparams.length;i++){
                    if(i!=0){
                        data+="&";
                    }
                    data+=URLEncoder.encode(pparams[i][0],"UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pparams[i][1],"UTF8");

            }
        }
        URL mylink=new URL(link);

        URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        Log.d("sssss",sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object tr) {
        super.onPostExecute(tr);            
        String result = (String)tr;
        try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("followlist");
        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String client_id=jObject.getString("client_id");
        GrtUserProfile(client_id);

        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

**Solve Problem With this Code :**

```
public void GrtUserProfile(String Cid) {

    String requestUrl= "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+Cid+"/"+"&access_token="+mInstagramSession.getAccessToken();

    new HTTPRequestClass().execute(requestUrl);

}

 class HTTPRequestClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         try {
                String url = urls[0];
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
                HttpEntity httpEntity       = httpResponse.getEntity();
                if (httpEntity == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Request returns empty result");
                }
                InputStream stream      = httpEntity.getContent();      
                String response = StringUtil.streamToString(stream);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                    throw new Exception(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

                }
                return response;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  return "";
            }

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String Response) {
        Log.i("Response", Response);
    }
 }
```

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException is caused due to network call you are doing on the main thread

Comment: Show how you call your AsyncTask.

Comment: `after get data from my server i try to get more info ` ???? Which data did you get already before you execute the code that follows?

Comment: Please explain in detail what your timer setup is doing. Does it trigger every second or what?

Comment: So you have two asynctasks... one for downloading and one for uploading and further info. Pretty unclear what all happens.

Comment: First it is unclear for what you use this timer construction. Second its unclear when, where and how you start the second asynctask. And for which task you get the exception.

Comment: @greenapps : I have a list from Instagramm to show to users for follow like or etc i try to get list and then get info from IG and ..... and my problem solved with add new AsyncTask for HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Timer to cancel async task you can set timeout for HttpURLConnection

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Boolean> {
         protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... urls) {
             try {
                   HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                   con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                  con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds

                   return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);

                 } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                        return false;
                 } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        return false;
                 }
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             showDialog("Downloaded " + result );
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for Code, you right, but after this i use from HttpClient  and exception is for HttpResponse any solution for that ?